# Convert raw PostgreSQL CTE query to Django ORM using django-cte

Tags: django-orm

I have an example raw PostgreSQL query like this (from [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)):

```sql
WITH regional_sales AS (
        SELECT region, SUM(amount) AS total_sales
        FROM orders
        GROUP BY region
     ), top_regions AS (
        SELECT region
        FROM regional_sales
        WHERE total_sales > (SELECT SUM(total_sales)/10 FROM regional_sales)
     )
SELECT region,
       product,
       SUM(quantity) AS product_units,
       SUM(amount) AS product_sales
FROM orders
WHERE region IN (SELECT region FROM top_regions)
GROUP BY region, product;
```

I would like to convert that to Django model using `django-cte`, anybody knows how to convert this?